# How do I remove the search icon from wordpress menu and replace with "Search"

Tags: wordpress, search, menu, icons

The title says it all, I want to remove the search icon from the menu bar and replace it simple with the word "Search"

My `style.css` looks like this:

```
.site-header .search-field {
    background-color: transparent;
    /*background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);*/
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 34px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    transition:         width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

And nowhere else in any file can I find a link to the `search-icon.png` image.

[image: Search icon]

[image: Search icon with textbox]

[image: Bad position]

The last screenshot shows that the search box has dropped down. How can I position it in line horizontally with the other menu items, as far off to the right as the menu will allow?

The CSS used to produce the nag-menu is:

```
/**
 * 4.2 Navigation
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

.main-navigation {
    z-index: 1000;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*max-width: 1920px;*/
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-height: 45px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}

.nav-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-menu li a {
    color: #3c3c3c;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    /*line-height: 1;*/
    /*padding: 15px 20px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover {
    /*background-color: #220e10;*/
    /*background-color: #333333;*/
    color: #666;
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu,
.nav-menu .children {
    /*background-color: #220e10;*/
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /*border: 2px solid #f7f5e7;*/
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 0;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    top: 100%;
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
.nav-menu .children ul {
    border-left: 0;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a,
.nav-menu ul ul a {
    color: #3c3c3c;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a:hover,
.nav-menu ul ul a:hover {
    /*background-color: #db572f;*/
}

ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav-menu .current_page_item > a,
.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a {
    /*background-color: #666;*/

    color: #666;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
}

/* Arrow underneath */

/*
.nav-menu .current_page_item > a:after,
.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a:after,
.nav-menu .current-menu-item > a:after,
.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    display:block;

    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #666;

    left: 50%;

    margin-left: -6px;
}
*/

.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    /*background-color: #f7f5e7;*/
    /*background-color: #fff;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1600px;
    width: 100%;
}

.site-header .search-form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}

.site-header .search-field {
    background-color: transparent;
    /*background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);*/
    /*background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;*/
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*height: 37px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*padding: 0 0 0 34px;*/
    position: relative;
    /*-webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    transition:         width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;*/
    /*width: 0;*/
    width: 120px;
    min-height: 45px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.site-header .search-field:focus {
    /*background-color: #fff;*/
    /*border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #666666;*/
    cursor: text;
    outline: 0;
    color: #666666;
    /*width: 230px;*/
}
```

Comment: It'll depend on the theme you're using but you should be able to go into the theme files and change it to what you'd like. It'll likely be in header.php. Do you have any sample code or a link?

Comment: I have commented it out in the CSS file so it shouldn't show up. The link to `search-icon.png` can't be found anywhere else!

Comment: No, the title doesn't says it all.

Comment: Care to offer any other help other than that comment brasofilo, with a reputation of over 6000 surely you could understand what I am asking. If not, why comment?

Comment: @Mike What theme are you using? I really can't assess the problem without a better idea of how the theme is put together.

Comment: It is my own custom theme based on the twenty-thirteen theme. `searchform.php` doesn't exist so I have looked in the `general-template.php` file and there is no mention of the `search-icon.png` image there either.

Comment: Removing the background image in firebug worked on the [twenty-thirteen preview](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen). Is this a child theme of twenty-thirteen or are you hacking it up? Try `background-image: none !important;`

Comment: @elkirkmo I have found it, it is still in the `style.css` file in the `@media print` section. Why is Safari displaying this?

Comment: Because Safari is weird.

Comment: Do you know how I can show just the text "Search" instead?

Comment: @Mike, exactly, I've seen thousands of Q&A's to know the quality we expect here. I've removed my downvote and vote-to-close. The system says it all: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G3SUx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

All you honestly have to do is change the `width` to about >100px and remove the `background-img`. That will show the placeholder text and when you click on it, it'll launch the animation like before.

Comment: I actually preferred it how you had it first, removed all the unnecessary stuff. However, the position is now messed up. I will re-edit my original question if I may.

Comment: You've got competing `position` rules. You've got `position: absolute; right: 20px;` and then you've got `position: relative;` overriding it a few lines later. Just remove the `position: relative;` and it should work itself out.

Comment: Never mind, they're not actually competing. I misread the class names.

Comment: Try reducing the `width` of `.site-header .search-field` to something smaller, like `50px`. I think it might be too wide to fit and so it's just bumping down.